# Free mind-mapping software for Windows and Android

Tags: windows, gratis, android, cross-platform, mind-mapping

I'm searching for a free mind-mapping software for both Windows and Android. It should be able to sync my mind-maps across all devices.

The only feature that is a must-have (basically what every piece of software of this kind does) is that it should be able to create and arrange cloud-graphs.

There are several ones, like Simplemind, Mindjet, etc., but it looks like there is none which is completely free for mobile *and* desktop. Does anyone know one?

Comment: Not for Android, but Xmind is great on Windows https://www.xmind.net/ and free for normal levels of use

Comment: Thank you, but it has to be cross-platform. I've used Freemind - it's also great on Windows but no mobile version.

Comment: Make it in the cloud: http://marcodiiga.github.io/knode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mindomo and MindMeister both have free Android apps, and they give you up to three free online maps at any one time.  Both can be run from Windows in a browser to access the same maps.  MindMeister is my preferred one.

If three maps is not enough, and I guess it won't be, you could try some of the all-free, browser-based ones to see how they work with touch on the Android.  Try Coggle (I reviewed it here: http://www.mind-mapping.org/blog/2013/09/coggle-it/ ) It's multi-user, with chat.
Or MindMup, review: http://www.mind-mapping.org/blog/2013/11/mindmup-browser-based-free-easy-and-open-source/

Comment: I guess I'll accept your answer, tried Coggle and I think I'll go with it. I didn't want to use a browser-based one, but since it works fine with Chrome on Android it might work out. Thanks!

Comment: Update on Coggle (coggle.it): as of today it offers for free 3 private diagrams + unlimited public ones